# How to explain this Javascript Syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

I was looking at a few things in Javascript. When I got to the call() function I had a look at this on the [mozilla js developer page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

**Syntax:**

```
fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

I understand what the function does and how it operates but what on earth is that syntax trying to say? Why is there a comma right after that bracket?

`[,`

Similarly when I was looking up the reduce() function I understand how it works but the syntax shows this:

```
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

Shouldn't this be something like  arr.reduce(callback, initialvalue) instead?

As a noob, the syntax leads me to believe that callback is an array and it has an empty first element and a second element called initialValue. Is there somewhere that I can read about this syntax so that it makes sense, or could some kind person please provide me with some clarity?

EDIT: Also callback refers to a function yes? So why is it callback[] and not callback()?

Answer (score 5):

`[...]` indicates that what is inside is optional. For example, `arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])` can be either `arr.reduce(callback)` or `arr.reduce(callback, initialValue)`.

The comma is right there meaning that if you will include the second argument, you must put the comma.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If you look at the second example I provided there is no [...] however. So how am I supposed to know that one of the arguments is optional?

Comment: Does it imply that the element after the comma (initialValue) is optional and that I must provide the comma if I use this argument? That would make sense. I do wonder though why callback is callback[] and not callback()

Comment: Just for clarity - it is not a JS syntax, it is just a documentation syntax.

Answer (score 2):

That is a documentation convention and not actual JS syntax.

Square brackets indicate the argument is optional.

The ellipsis indicates that *any number* of arguments can go there.

> ```
> fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
> ```

means you could say:

```
 fun.call(foo);
 fun.call(foo, 1);
 fun.call(foo, 1, 2);
 fun.call(foo, 1, 2, 3);
 fun.call(foo, 1, 2, 3, 4);
 fun.call(foo, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

etc

> ```
> arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
> ```

means you coul dsay:

```
arr.reduce(foo);
```

or

```
arr.reduce(foo, bar);
```

… but **not**

```
arr.reduce(foo, bar, baz);
```